# Ignore urls that have no parameters in robots.txt

Tags: mod-rewrite, robots.txt

I have a pretty url like this.

```
http://example.com/category/shoes
```

I want to `disallow` the `url` if there is no `shoes parameter` in the url because without the parameter the page will be redirected to homepage.

So i tried something like this in `robots.txt` file

```
Disallow: /category/
Allow: /category/*?*
```

I am not sure if the above attempt is correct or not? Or what is the correct way of achieving it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To block:

http://example.com/category/

without blocking:

http://example.com/category/whatever

You can use the $ operator:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /category/$
```

The $ means "end of url". Note that the $ operator is not supported by all web robots. It is a common extension that works for all of the major search engines, but it was not part of the original robots.txt standard.

The following will not work:

```
Disallow: /category/
Allow: /category/*?*
```

This will block **any** URL path that starts with /category/, except when the URL also contains a question mark. This is probably not what you want.

Comment: I researched a bit and came to know that Google and Bing both respect the `$` operator.